# cron が sendmail で送ってくるローカルの mail について

Tags: unix, mail, sendmail

ローカルの mac や amazon linux 上のデフォルトの設定では、 cron の実行が失敗したときなどにおいては、 `sendmail` コマンドがインストールされている場合、それ経由で cron 実行ユーザーに対して mail を送るような挙動になると思っています。(そして、各ユーザーは `mailx` コマンドなどでそのメールの内容を確認できる)

この、「ローカルユーザーに対してメールを送る」という挙動について疑問がいくつか生じていて、おそらく一連の知識なのだろうけれども、そのソース情報を見つけられずにいます。具体的には:

- sendmail がローカルユーザーに対してメールを送る場合、「ローカルユーザー当のメール保存ディレクトリ・ファイル形式」を前提にして、今まで送られたデータを読み込んで、その末尾に今送られた新規メールを append するような動作になると思いますが、この「ローカルユーザー当のメール保存ディレクトリ・ファイル形式」に名前はついていますか？

  - 具体的には `/var/mail/ユーザー名`に保存されることになると思っていますが、このファイル形式・保存場所の規約に名前はありますか？
- 上記の「ローカルユーザー当のメール保存ディレクトリ・ファイル形式」は、おそらくローカルメールだけではなく、外部サーバーからのメール受信にも用いられるのかな、と思っていますが、この認識は正しいでしょうか。

  - もしくは、このディレクトリは、「ローカルユーザー間メール」のみに利用されるディレクトリでしょうか。
  - その場合、この「ローカルユーザー間メール受信」自体にプロトコル名称がついていそうですが、その名称などはありますでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

[FHS](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) で決められたディレクトリ構造の一部です。

ディストリビューションによって異なる場合がありますが、通常`/var/mail`は`/var/spool/mail`へのシンボリックリンクであり、`/var/spool`以下がメールや印刷ジョブなどの「キュー」を保存しておく場所として利用されています。

[各ディレクトリの役割を知ろう (サブディレクトリ編) ：Windowsユーザーに教えるLinuxの常識（3） - ＠IT](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/0109/07/news002_2.html)

> **/var/spool**
>   spoolはSimultaneous Peripheral Operation On-Lineの省略形で、もともとはIBM用語です。本来は、動作の遅い周辺機器に対して効率よくデータを送るためのバッファです。転じて、FIFO（First In First Out）の、いわゆる「キュー」と呼ばれるバッファとして使われているようです。
>
> (中略)
>
> また、sendmailを使ったメールサーバであれば、/var/spool/mailの下に各ユーザー名と同じファイルがあります。これが、いわゆるメールボックスです。ユーザーに送られたメールは、いったんここに保存されます。その後、mailコマンドで読み出したり、POP3でメーラーに読み込んだりするわけです。最近では、MTAとしてqmailを使うサーバもあるようですが、その場合は/var/spool/mailを使わず、直接各ユーザーのホームディレクトリにメールを配送するのが一般的です。

Answer (score 1):

> 「ローカルユーザー当のメール保存ディレクトリ・ファイル形式」に名前はついていますか？

yes.

「mbox 形式」と呼ばれます。[mbox - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox)

他には、1 メール 1 ファイルで保存する「Maildir形式」というのもあります。[Maildir - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maildir)

例えば Postfix はメール保存形式を mbox にするか、Maildir にするかオプションがあったりします。[Postfix設定パラメータ](http://www.postfix-jp.info/trans-2.3/jhtml/postconf.5.html#home_mailbox)

> 「ローカルユーザー当のメール保存ディレクトリ・ファイル形式」は[略]外部サーバーからのメール受信にも用いられる

yes.

Answer (score 0):

保存ディレクトリ(`/var/mail` や `/var/spool/mail`)に決まった用語があるかどうか不明ですが、一般的には「メールスプールディレクトリ」と呼ぶと思います。そこでのファイル形式は「[mbox](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox)」と呼びます。共通のスプールディレクトリにファイルを置かず、ユーザのホームディレクトリ内にmbox形式のファイルを作るような設定もMTAによっては可能です。

mbox形式以外に、「[Maildir](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maildir)」というのもあります。

通常、ローカル配信でも外部からの受信でも使われます。